# Split the string in oracle query using regexp_substr

Tags: regex, substr

I have a string like `R09801E_ZJDE0001`. I am able to split the first part of the string, the part before `_` (`R09801E`), by using below systax

```
regexp_substr('R09801E_ZJDE0001', '[^_]+', 1, 1)
```

Can anyone please suggest how to get the second part of the string after the `_` (`ZJDE0001`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually do this with the base string functions:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTR(col, 1, INSTR(col, '_') - 1) AS first_part,
    SUBSTR(col, INSTR(col, '_') + 1) AS second_part
FROM yourTable;
```

[image]

### Demo

The reason I suggest this approach is that using `SUBSTR` with `INSTR` would likely outperform a regex based solution.

If you really want to use a regex approach, then I recommend using `REGEXP_REPLACE`:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('R09801E_ZJDE0001', '.*_', '') AS second_part
FROM dual;
```

This would strip off everything coming before, up to and including, the underscore, which leaves us with the second part.

Comment: + this is much simpler than regex. I strongly guess more ppl learn string manipulation functions than ppl learning oracle regex.

Comment: @Chrᴉz It's more of a performance thing; there are many instances where using a regex engine is perfectly OK.  But, we don't have to use it just because it's available.